# ScrollView implementing more than 1 relativelayout

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, scrollview

This is my code

I need to Make it look like without Scrollview not stacking up
I can't make my LinearLayout xmlns:android to Scroll view because i doesn't want my toolbar to start moving around.

```js
 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context=".HistoryScreen">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_history"
            android:textColor="@color/TitleColor"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:text="@string/History3" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/show"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_down"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/show"
                    android:background="#000" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/hide"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_up"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description_text1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/description_text1"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:text="@string/History2" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/show1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text1"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_down"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/show1"
                    android:background="#000" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/hide1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text1"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_up"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description_text2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/description_text2"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:text="@string/history4">

                </TextView>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/show2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text2"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_down"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/show2"
                    android:background="#000" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/hide2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text2"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_up"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>'
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHtXq.png(Without ScrollView)
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBcRz.png(With ScrollView)

Comment: Your questions seems to me a little unclear. What is it exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: you can't have more than one direct child of scroll view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `RelativeLayout` inside the ScrollView to `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` and it should work.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:context=".HistoryScreen">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="370dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_history"
            android:textColor="@color/TitleColor"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:text="@string/History3" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/show"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_down"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/show"
                    android:background="#000" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/hide"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_up"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description_text1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/description_text1"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:text="@string/History2" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/show1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text1"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_down"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/show1"
                    android:background="#000" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/hide1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text1"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_up"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description_text2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/description_text2"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:text="@string/history4">

                </TextView>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/show2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text2"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_down"
                    android:clickable="true" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/show2"
                    android:background="#000" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/hide2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/description_text2"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_up"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If it did, then you can mark it as accepted answer. So that the people who stumble upon this question in the future can benefit from the same. :)